# JS отправка формы по чекбоксу

Tags: javascript, jquery

идея такая - при выборе чекбокса, должна идти отправка формы

```
<form name="upsert" id ="myForm" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" id="slideThree" name="check"  <?= $check ?>/>
 <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE ="Сохранить">
                </form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slideThree").change(function () {
            $("#myForm").submit();           
        });
    });
</script>
```

при клике на кнопке уходят данные от чекбокса. при клике на чекбокс отправляется все кроме значения чекбокса

Answer (score 1):

Ну есть такой вариант.

```
<form name="upsert" id ="myForm" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" id="slideThree" name="check"  <?= $check ?>/>
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE ="Сохранить">
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slideThree").on('click', function (e) {
            e = e.originalEvent;
            if(e){//Это чтоб в консоль ошибки не лезли
                e.preventDefault();//Это прекращает стандартное действие
                e.stopPropagation();//Это прекращает действия последующие после стандартного
            }
            $("#myForm").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

А проще было поставить disabled на чекбокс и все)

Answer (score 0):

если посмотреть здесь, то вообще эмулируют клик  по сабмиту. больще на хак похоже

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480316/jquery-submit-form-onchange

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#widgetFieldInput').change(function(){
       $('#select_date').click();
    });
});
```